# Is it possible to outsource export settings?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I'm building a website using `org-mode` (specifically a project exported with `ox-twbs`). I want a navagation bar at the top of each page in my website. For example, one of my pages looks like this:

```
#+Title: My Page
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <ul class="nav nav-tabs"> <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li> <li role="presentation"><a href="file:///home/brian/mypages/teaching/index.html">Teaching</a></li> <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li></ul>


This is my page. It was generated with the =ox-twbs= package for =emacs=.
```

The second line creates a tab menu at the top of the page.

My issue is that I want every page of my website to have the same tab menu. However, I'd rather not edit every `org` file in my directory every time I want to edit the tab menu.

It would be nice if I could maintain the tab menu in an external file

```
$ cat ~/tabmenu.html
<ul class="nav nav-tabs"> <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li> <li role="presentation"><a href="file:///home/brian/mypages/teaching/index.html">Teaching</a></li> <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Messages</a></li></ul>
```

and import this file into every `#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA` with something like this:

```
#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA: <code to import ~/tabmenu.html>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Do you know about #+INCLUDE?

Comment: Would `#+INCLUDE` play nicely with `#+HTML_HEAD_EXTRA`?